# Meteor - Send email with attachment from an INPUT TYPE FILE

Tags: file, email, meteor, attachment, filereader

I want to send an email when a form is submitted and one of the input is a type=file and I can't figure out how to attach this to the email.

I'm working with Meteor and the package "email" from Meteor. I know this package is based on mailComposer and I have to provide some informations in an object. 
But I don't know how to provide some of them since I don't want the file of the user to be uploaded on my server. 
I think I need to get the path and the filename. Filename is easy but how to get the path ?

I've tried it with FileReader but it created a "fake" path and it don't seem to work.

This is Meteor method I call on server-side:

```
 sendEmail: function (to, from, subject, text, attachments) {
  check([to, from, subject, text], [String]);
  this.unblock();
  Email.send({
    to: to,
    from: from,
    subject: subject,
    html: text,
    attachments: attachments
  });
}
```

And here's the informations I provide on client-side:

```
readFile(inputResume.files[0], function(e) {
   var file = {
      filename: $(e.target).find('[name="resume"]')[0].files[0].name,
      path: e.target.result
   } 
});    
function readFile(file, onLoadCallback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = onLoadCallback;
}
Meteor.call('sendEmail',
  'email', // To
  'email', // From
  'subject', // Subject
  'text' // Message
  'file' // Attachment
);
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> The attachment is an array type.

@param {Object[]} [options.attachments] Array of attachment objects, as

described in the [mailcomposer documentation](https://github.com/andris9/mailcomposer/blob/7c0422b2de2dc61a60ba27cfa3353472f662aeb5/README.md#add-attachments).

Comment: But how do I get my options ? I can't figure out how to get the filePath properly for that to work

Comment: Please go through the documentation you can fine "contents - String or a Buffer contents for the attachment"

Comment: I am facing the same problem. @AudeFi did you get solution for this how to send attachment object in send email method

Comment: Did you check this: https://github.com/nodemailer/mailcomposer/blob/7c0422b2de2dc61a60ba27cfa3353472f662aeb5/README.md#add-attachments